# Dual Axis highcharts using html table

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am trying to draw a chart using HighChart with html table as in the following example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/e1sphL3p/3/

in this example, everything is well but when I tried it in my project the line is located behind the bar

How can I fix it

Comment: It all depends on how you are loading series to your chart. If last series is column, it will be on top of your spline series. If your last series is spline, it will be on top of column chart. Could you show live example of your chart? Like jsFiddle?

Comment: it works well in live example as shown in jsfiddle. but the issue appear in my project

Comment: I know that it works fine in provided example, that is why I asked you to show us your project - so we can investigate the problem :)